# Why is jQuery remove throwing .attr exception in IE8

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

```
_removeSelection : function(e, refocus) {

  var thisObj      = e.data,
      lineItem     = $(this).closest('li'),
      templateData = lineItem.data('templateData');

  thisObj.element.trigger('beforeRemoveSelection',[templateData]);

  lineItem.remove();

  thisObj._selection_items = $(thisObj._selections).find('li');

  if ( ( refocus != 'undefined' && refocus === true ) || refocus == 'undefined') {
    thisObj.refocus();
  }

  thisObj.element.trigger('toggleSelection');
  thisObj.element.trigger('limitNotHit', [true]);
  thisObj.element.trigger('removeSelection',[templateData]);

}
```

Everything logs fine and it appears to execute fine. However after all my code runs I get an exception:

"Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'"

So I have a loop that calls the function X times, but it only runs the function to completion once.

**EDIT**: The loop triggers a click on an element which runs that function. If I manually trigger the click using firebug, it still throws exception

**EDIT 2**: The exception is thrown at line 4550 in jquery-1.6.2.js

Doing `lineItem[0].parentNode.removeChild( lineItem[0] );` also causes delayed exception. Looks like @zzzz is right about some weird cache cleanup.

**This only happens when using .trigger('click'), not when actually clicking on the element**

Comment: I don't see in this snippet where you're calling getAttribute. Please post all your code.

Comment: I'm not, it's somewhere within jQuery and I can't get a good stack trace from IE. No other browsers have this issue. If I remove that line literally everything works aside from visually removing the element. Using .detach() has same result

Comment: I've also console logged around every single click, mouseup, blur, focus on the screen to see them all run fine too so I'm at a loss for when this exception happens since it's always after all the code I wrote ran. Never seen this behavior before.

Comment: I've had issues in IE7 with older versions of jQuery when selecting and then removing a random result from some `$("selector")`. When running that same code again (not even in a loop, but in a separate, timed event), sometimes elements that had already been removed earlier were somehow found and "selected" again — obviously getting one into trouble. Some odd caching issue, I guess. Are you using a recent version of jQuery? Are you sure IE8 is not running in compatibility mode, actually working as IE7 then? (Which is the default for intranet sites, in IE8.)

Comment: could you post the code where you assign lineItem?

Comment: Okay there's the whole function. It runs from start to finish. Throws exception. Removing lineItem.remove prevents exception.

Comment: Happens with IE8 browser mode and document mode. I just upgraded to the most recent jQuery although it was still an issue on 1.4 ( finally made the jump from 1.4 to 1.6 )

Comment: I filed a bug with .remove that may also be impacting this code. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10138

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is because IE bubbles the click event to a node that no longer exists (and then jQuery tries to do something with that?).

I assume because your click removes the parent element, so when it tries to bubble to that element it breaks.

Anyways, I have seen the exact same thing in IE when using backbone.js to re-render on change events - change event bubbles up but node no longer exists (because its been rendered again so it's a new node) and it fires this error.

Using event.stopPropagation [ http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ ] has worked to solve this for me in the past, give it a shot.

Comment: Wow the exact same backbone problem occurred for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say it's a bug. There is an unhandled exception in sizzle, it only happens in browsers not supporting querySelectorAll (like IE7 or IE8+ in compatibility mode) .

The attribute-handler for type receives an argument that is not an element-node.

If function seems to work as expected just catch and ignore this error.

add this after you import your jquery file.

```
<script>
 if($.browser.msie)
 {
 jQuery.find.selectors.attrHandle.type=function( elem ) {   
       try{return elem.getAttribute( "type" );}catch(e){return'';}
    }
 }
</script>
```

I realise its a hack.. but better than an error.

Comment: That looks like it shoulda worked but it was no dice. Check edit above for jQuery line numbers